# Using the window.open Method

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a jsp file which, according to its current functionality, opens an attachment in the same window of the application. I want it to open the attachment in a new window, even if its a popup.

I have tried to use the 'window.open' feature but i get a paranthesis error. The major problem is i dont want to lose the existing mapping hence im not writing the statement from beginning.

```
  <a
   href="<%=UrlBuilder.getServletRoot()+"ProgramAttachmentRetriveServletactionId=retrieve 
   &attachmentType=I"%>
   &attachmentId=<%=attachmentInt.getAttachmentId()+"&programSysId="%>
   <%=request.getParameter("programSysId")%>">                              
   <%=attachmentInt.getAttachmentDesc()%> 
  </a>
```

As you might see, i am opening the attachment via a hyperlink. I would want it to open in a seperate window. How can i do it using 'window.open'. If its not possible via this feature, how else can i open that?

Comment: Can't you simply add `target="_blank"` property to the `a href` tag?

Comment: Thanks! Figured how it works. Don't know why didnt try this earlier.

Comment: I think it will be the best if you write an anwser to your own question and accept it, just so people who search for similar problems see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question was quite simple actually, rather than changing a lot of lines, i couldve directly used the '*target="_blank"*'for the href tag. The '_blank' attribute makes the attachment open up in a new window.